# How to put the letters under the arrows tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am currently using Tikz in order to draw a fluxogram. Do you know how put the letters "Sim" (Yes) and "Não" (No) below the arrow?

Thank you.

My MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
 % Fluxograma
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shapes.geometric}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
\centering
\node (start) [startstop] {Início do Processamento};
\node (pro2a) [process, below of=start] {Definir os Métodos de Solução};
        \draw [arrow] (start) -- (pro2a);
\node (pro2b) [process, below of=pro2a] {Definir os Controlos da Solução};
        \draw [arrow] (pro2a) -- (pro2b);
\node (pro2c) [process, below of=pro2b] {Definir os Monitores da Solução};
        \draw [arrow] (pro2b) -- (pro2c);
\node (pro2d) [process, below of=pro2c] {Inicializar a Simulação};
        \draw [arrow] (pro2c) -- (pro2d);
\node (pro2e) [process, below of=pro2d] {Efetuar o cálculo numérico};
        \draw [arrow] (pro2d) -- (pro2e);
\node (dec1)  [decision, below of=pro2e, yshift=-2cm] {Verificar convergência};
\node (pro2f) [process, right of=dec1, xshift=7cm] {Modificar paramêtros da malha ou da Solução};
            \draw [arrow] (pro2e) -- (dec1);
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=east] {Não} (pro2f);
\node (dec2)  [decision, below of=dec1, yshift=-3.5cm] {Verificar Exactidão};
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=south] {Sim} (dec2);
    %   \draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node[anchor=south] {yes} (stop);
\node (stop) [startstop, below of=dec2, yshift=-2cm] {Fim do Processamento};
        \draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node[anchor=south] {Sim} (stop);
            \draw [arrow] (dec2) -| node[anchor=east] (-1,0) {Não} (pro2f);
%\node (out1) [io, below of=pro2a] {Output};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Propriedades Físicas de um escoamento]{Propriedades Físicas de um escoamento, retirado de \cite{Tu2013}.}
\label{flux:fluxograma}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Does `anchor=east` for the `Sim` nodes, and `anchor=south` for the `Não` nodes do what you want? (You have the opposite, south for yes, east for no.)

Answer (score 4):

To show, how this simple flow chart can be written on more concise way and how to use correct syntax for positioning (not `... of= ...` but `...=of ...` with use `positioning` library), than instead of obsolete `\tikzstyle` use `\tikzset` and for cases, that you have more predefined styles, I suggest to give a name to `\tikzset` dedicated for drawing flowcharts.

In MWE below is used two more libraries: `chains` and `quotes` for positioning of nodes and labeling edges respectively. For arrows I suggest to use `arrows.meta` library instead of `arrows`. Also for simple connection of nodes (without labeling of edges) is very handy to use `join` macro, which I added to `base` node definitions:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, positioning, quotes, shapes.geometric}

 \makeatletter % because join reset definition contain @
\tikzset{flowchart/.style={
     base/.style = {draw, text width=42mm, minimum height=1cm,
                    align=flush center, on chain, join=by arrow},
startstop/.style = {base, rounded corners,  fill=red!30},
       io/.style = {trapezium, 
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                    trapezium stretches=true,
                    base, fill=blue!30},
  process/.style = {base, fill=orange!30},
 decision/.style = {diamond, draw, minimum width=1cm, aspect=1.5, 
                    align=center, fill=green!30, on chain, join=by arrow},
    arrow/.style = {semithick,-Stealth},
join reset/.code = {\def\tikz@after@path{}} % for disconnecting of join arrows between nodes
                            },
        }% end of tikzset
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[flowchart,
node distance = 6mm and 12mm,
  start chain = going below
                        ]
\node (start) [startstop]   {Início do Processamento};
\node (pro2a) [process]     {Definir os Métodos de Solução};
\node (pro2b) [process]     {Definir os Controlos da Solução};
\node (pro2c) [process]     {Definir os Monitores da Solução};
\node (pro2d) [process]     {Inicializar a Simulação};
\node (pro2e) [process]     {Efetuar o cálculo numérico};
\node (dec1)  [decision]    {Verificar convergência};
\node (dec2)  [decision]    {Verificar Exactidão};
\node (stop)  [startstop]   {Fim do Processamento};
%
\node (pro2f) [process, join reset,
               right=of dec1] {Modificar paramêtros da malha ou da Solução};
%
\draw [arrow] (dec1) to ["Sim"] (dec2);
\draw [arrow] (dec2) to ["Sim"] (stop);
\draw [arrow] (pro2f) |- (pro2e);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) to ["Não"] (pro2f);
\draw [arrow] (dec2) -| node[right] {Não} (pro2f);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[]{my caption}
\label{flux:fluxograma_Fase_de_Processamento}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, I slightly change flowchart style. Now all elements has the same width and in the cases, when text is longer than node width, it is broken into more (two) lines. If you not liked this, just replace in `base/.style` option `text width` with `minimum width` and remove `align=flush center`.

Answer (score 1):

For Torbjorn T., Yes. Thank you for your help! I use east, south and west to solve the problem

Result now:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
 % Fluxograma
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shapes.geometric}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
\centering
\node (start) [startstop] {Início do Processamento};
\node (pro2a) [process, below of=start] {Definir os Métodos de Solução};
        \draw [arrow] (start) -- (pro2a);
\node (pro2b) [process, below of=pro2a] {Definir os Controlos da Solução};
        \draw [arrow] (pro2a) -- (pro2b);
\node (pro2c) [process, below of=pro2b] {Definir os Monitores da Solução};
        \draw [arrow] (pro2b) -- (pro2c);
\node (pro2d) [process, below of=pro2c] {Inicializar a Simulação};
        \draw [arrow] (pro2c) -- (pro2d);
\node (pro2e) [process, below of=pro2d] {Efetuar o cálculo numérico};
        \draw [arrow] (pro2d) -- (pro2e);
\node (dec1)  [decision, below of=pro2e, yshift=-2cm] {Verificar convergência};
\node (pro2f) [process, right of=dec1, xshift=7cm] {Modificar paramêtros da malha ou da Solução};
            \draw [arrow] (pro2e) -- (dec1);
            \draw [arrow] (pro2f) |- (pro2e);
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=south] {Não} (pro2f);
\node (dec2)  [decision, below of=dec1, yshift=-3.5cm] {Verificar Exactidão};
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=east] {Sim} (dec2);
    %   \draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node[anchor=south] {yes} (stop);
\node (stop) [startstop, below of=dec2, yshift=-2cm] {Fim do Processamento};
        \draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node[anchor=east] {Sim} (stop);
            **\draw [arrow] (dec2) -| node[anchor=west] {Não} (pro2f);**
%\node (out1) [io, below of=pro2a] {Output};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[]
\label{flux:fluxograma_Fase_de_Processamento}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can chain style definitions, making it easy to consistently change the formatting of your flow diagram.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
 % Fluxograma
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shapes.geometric}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{nodestyle} = [near start]           % <--- added
\tikzstyle{yesnode} = [nodestyle,xshift=1em]   % <--- added
\tikzstyle{nonode} = [nodestyle,yshift=-1em]   % <--- added

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
\centering
\node (start) [startstop] {Início do Processamento};
\node (pro2a) [process, below of=start] {Definir os Métodos de Solução};
        \draw [arrow] (start) -- (pro2a);
\node (pro2b) [process, below of=pro2a] {Definir os Controlos da Solução};
        \draw [arrow] (pro2a) -- (pro2b);
\node (pro2c) [process, below of=pro2b] {Definir os Monitores da Solução};
        \draw [arrow] (pro2b) -- (pro2c);
\node (pro2d) [process, below of=pro2c] {Inicializar a Simulação};
        \draw [arrow] (pro2c) -- (pro2d);
\node (pro2e) [process, below of=pro2d] {Efetuar o cálculo numérico};
        \draw [arrow] (pro2d) -- (pro2e);
\node (dec1)  [decision, below of=pro2e, yshift=-2cm] {Verificar convergência};
\node (pro2f) [process, right of=dec1, xshift=7cm] {Modificar paramêtros da malha ou da Solução};
            \draw [arrow] (pro2e) -- (dec1);
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[nonode] {Não} (pro2f);   % <--- using nodestyle "nonode"
\node (dec2)  [decision, below of=dec1, yshift=-3.5cm] {Verificar Exactidão};
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[yesnode] {Sim} (dec2);   % <--- using nodestyle "yesnode"
    %   \draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node[anchor=south] {yes} (stop);
\node (stop) [startstop, below of=dec2, yshift=-2cm] {Fim do Processamento};
        \draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node[yesnode] {Sim} (stop);
            \draw [arrow] (dec2) -| node[nonode] (-1,0) {Não} (pro2f);
%\node (out1) [io, below of=pro2a] {Output};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Propriedades Físicas de um escoamento]{Propriedades Físicas de um escoamento, retirado de \cite{Tu2013}.}
\label{flux:fluxograma}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]